# Merge a branch into the folder of another branch

Tags: git

I have a branch A with a folder named `foo`. Another branch named B has only the content of the folder `foo`. Is it possible to merge the branch B into the folder `foo` of branch A?

The branch A contains for example

```
foo/
    hello_world.c
goo/
    AliceAndTom.c
```

The branch B contains only the content of the folder foo/

```
./
    hello_world.c
    hello_world.h
```

The result I want in the branch A after merging branch B:

```
foo/
    hello_world.c
    hello_world.h
goo/
    AliceAndTom.c
```

**Edit**:
branch B was created using git command `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter dir/to/filter -- subdir_branch`

Comment: You should be able to. Git does an acceptable (not flawless, *acceptable*) task at trying to figure out file renames. But the file .h will probably end up in the base dir, not inside foo.... but you can move it before finishing the merge if you run `git merge --on-commit`. You move the file to the location where you want it and to be and then `git merge --continue`.

Comment: Move the folders first in one of the branches, then merge. Git doesn't move files for you.

Comment: Git merging does not behave the way you seem to think it does.  The result of your proposed merge would likely have _two_ `hello_world.c` files in it, one in the `foo/` folder and the other at the root level.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've seen git figure out renames and apply changes accordingly. I know it's not flawless but it's worth giving it a shot and see what happens. Worst case scenario: `git merge --abort`.

Comment: @eftshift0 You're right, and I didn't think of that.  Git could "figure out" that it is the same file.

Comment: Oh well... if you rewrote the history of the branch and they are unrelated, I make no promises.

Comment: @eftshift0 I assume you mean `--no-commit` instead of `--on-commit`? Otherwise that seems like a reasonable solution. The other option is to move the files to where they belong on branch B, commit those changes, and then merge into branch A.

Comment: right... `--no-commit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly merge it in.

There is some confusion in the comments about whether git's rename detection would help here.  Based on how you say the branch was created (with `filter-branch`), it most likely won't.  That's because the new branch probably doesn't have a common ancestor with the old branch.[1]

So first you have to solve the problem of getting git to recognize corresponding files from the branches; and then you have to solve the problem that it still won't know the most recent common ancestor for the two current states of that file, so the merge won't go smoothly.  (Each file that exists on both branches will conflict on, most likely, the entire file, not *really* merging anything.)

This is one of the problems that can arise from having "different content on different branches"; it's not how git is meant to work, and it can make integration of changes across branches quite tedious.

How tedious this would be depends on how much the files have changed on each branch since the `filter-branch` was run.  The most general procedure I can think of is:

(1) write a script that moves the files back to their subdirectory

(2) run `filter-branch` (with the above script as the tree filter) on the newer branch, creating yet another branch with structure closer to the original

(3) identify the last commit in the new branch that corresponds to a commit in the original branch

(4) use `git replace` to substitute the above-identified commit in place of the corresponding commit from the original branch.

(5) Now you should be able to merge the new branch to the original branch.  Then you can undo the `git replace` and possibly dispose of the new branch.

There are details to understand about each of these steps; it is *not* a simple procedure, so refer to the documentation for the involved commands if you want to pursue it.

---

[1] - More specifically, for rename detection to apply, git has to be looking at a patch that both removes a file, and creates another file (at a different path) with sufficiently similar content.

If you had branched from `master` and then, on the branch, made a commit in which you moved the files, you would now be looking at something like

```
x -- x -- O -- A <--(master)
           \
            x -- x -- B <--(bramch)
```

When merging `branch` to `master`, git will look at the patch between `O` and `B`, which meets the criteria for rename detection (as long as the moved file didn't change too much).

But `filter-branch` likely created a totally separate history

```
x -- x -- x -- A <--(master)

x -- x -- B <--(branch)
```

By default a merge will fail (no common history), and if you make it not fail (by saying to allow unrelated histories) then it will act as though there were a merge base with an empty `TREE` (i.e. no files).  The patch from that to `A` creates `foo/file`, and the patch from that to `B` creates `file`, but neither patch *both deletes the file at one path and creates it a the other*, so rename detection isn't going to happen.  The merge will create a second copy of the file.